# Properly designing(best location) this winform panel with generated controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to autogenerate and nicely display these controls on a panel *(panelMetaData)*.
Everything appears on the screen and are somewhat aligned, while some label text covers others etc. What can i do to have this controls properly located as it should ? Any location logic i am missing ?

`panelMetaData` was added using (drag and drop) from toolbox with properties like , `Dock:Fill`, `AutoSize:True` and `AutoScroll:True`.

[image]

***This is the method that creates the controls and positions them in the panel:*** (I removed some code to make the reading as easy as possible)

```
private void createAttributePanelControls()
{

    txtboxes = new List<Control>();
    labels = new List<Control>();
    valLabel = new List<Control>();
    combobox = new List<Control>();
    datetimetxtboxes = new List<Control>();

    int stringcnt = 0;
    int datecnt = 0;
    int listcnt = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < attributes.Length; i++)
    {
        Attribute attribute = attributes[i];

        labels.Add(CreateLabel(attribute.getDisplayName(), i, new Point(26, 56 + (i * 30))));
        panelMetaData.Controls.AddRange(labels.ToArray());


        switch (attribute.getType())
        {
            case DocAttribute.STRING:

                txtboxes.Add(CreateTextBox(attribute.getDisplayName(), i, new Point(labels[i].Width, labels[i].Top - 3)));
                 valLabel.Add(CreateValidationLabel(attribute.getDisplayName(), i, new Point(txtboxes[stringcnt].Width, labels[i].Top - 3)));  
                stringcnt++;
                break;
            case DocAttribute.DATE:

                datetimetxtboxes.Add(CreateDateTimePicker(attribute.getDisplayName(), i, new Point(labels[i].Widt, 56 + (i * 30))));
                 valLabel.Add(CreateValidationLabel(attribute.getDisplayName(), i, new Point(datetimetxtboxes[datecnt].Width, labels[i].Top - 3))); 
                datecnt++;
                break;
            case DocAttribute.LIST:
                combobox.Add(CreateComboBox(attribute.getDisplayName(), i, new Point(labels[i].Widt, 56 + (i * 30))));
                valLabel.Add(CreateValidationLabel(attribute.getDisplayName(), i, new Point(combobox[listcnt].Width, labels[i].Top - 3))); 
                listcnt++;
                break;
        }

    }

    if (txtboxes.Any()) panelMetaData.Controls.AddRange(txtboxes.ToArray());
    if (datetimetxtboxes.Any()) panelMetaData.Controls.AddRange(datetimetxtboxes.ToArray());
    if (combobox.Any()) panelMetaData.Controls.AddRange(combobox.ToArray());
    if (valLabel.Any()) panelMetaData.Controls.AddRange(valLabel.ToArray());
}
```

***These are the create methods:***

```
private TextBox CreateTextBox(string text, int value, Point location)
{
    TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
    textbox.Name =//somelogic
    textbox.Location = new Point(location.X, location.Y);
    textbox.Size = new Size(300, 21);

    return textbox;
}


private DateTimePicker CreateDateTimePicker(string text, int value, Point location)
{
    DateTimePicker datetextbox = new DateTimePicker();
    datetextbox.Name = //somelogic
    datetextbox.Location = new Point(location.X, location.Y);
    datetextbox.Size = new Size(300, 21);

    return datetextbox;
}


private ComboBox CreateComboBox(string text, int value, Point location)
{
    ComboBox combobox = new ComboBox();
    combobox.Name = //somelogic;
    combobox.Location = new Point(location.X, location.Y);
    combobox.Size = new Size(300, 21);

    return combobox;
}


private Label CreateLabel(string text, int value, Point location)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Name =//somelogic;
    label.Location = new Point(location.X, location.Y);
    label.AutoSize = true;

    return label;
}


private Label CreateValidationLabel(string text, int value, Point location)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Name = "vlb" + (text.Contains(".") ? text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf(".")) : text);
    label.Text = "*";
    label.Tag = value;
    label.Location = new Point(location.X, location.Y);
    label.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
    label.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    label.AutoSize = true;

    return label;
}
```

Comment: You can use a [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21wykkx(v=vs.110).aspx) with 2 columns, Also to show validation messages you can use an [`ErrorProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984104(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Might be unrelated, but move the line `panelMetaData.Controls.AddRange(labels.ToArray());` outside the `for` loop

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks will investigate !

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks, i forgot ! :)

Comment: Place the TextBoxes aligned to the largest label! So first place the labels (with their Texts, of course!), find their maximum Right value and then place the TextBoxes there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before reading the answer, it's better to consider:

- You can layout your controls more simple using a [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21wykkx(v=vs.110).aspx) with 2 columns.
- Also to show validation messages you can use an [`ErrorProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984104(v=vs.71).aspx) and set the error or clear the error for the controls using your error provider [`SetError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.seterror(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

But the wrong logic that I can see in your code, is:

You have not set any text for your labels while you have set the `AutoSize` property to `true` and then you added them to `panelMetaData.Controls` and it makes size of them `(0,0)`. Then you have used `Width` of label to position of controls and since `Width` of label is `0`, your controls will be shown with `Location.X = 0`

Comment: I will tryout what you said, thanks. Also i ommited the label.text, it is infact in the real code.

Comment: Assuming i have 2 columns, how will this be replaced to ? for the first column ? thanks. `panelMetaData.Controls.AddRange(txtboxes.ToArray());`

Comment: I think the @IvanStoev answer is correct (if you have set the text of labels before adding them to panel) and you should use `.Right` or `.Left` + `.Width`; But I think you should use `TableLayoutPanel` and tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add method accepts row and cell index.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that you use `Control.Width` property as a base for the next control location. You should really use `Control.Right` property for that purpose.

Comment: Actually this is while better still bound to create an ugly jagged look.

Comment: @TaW Correct, but since I've seen both styles to be used, I assume OP is trying to get that jagged look, while TableLayoutPanel is specifically made for what you are talking about.

Comment: Thank you. for this is the answer to my question but as you both advised, table layouts are better. So i used that.